# Formula to find correct answer which is difficult when values change

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Am not sure which formula fits on below scenerio if I try vlookup and if formula does not possible. It is really little bit tricky and difficult
Let me explain in short

**Table**

```
 Name         Amounts      comments 
 A               O         FOUND DATA MISSING
 A            not zero      FOUND DATA RECEIVED
 B            amounts       Found data in dept
```

in above table amount field will change as per expenses . Could you please anyone help me to get the results

Rule is fixed only "A" name difficult here because if amount is 0 then different comment and Amount if there any values then different comment

Could you please help on above problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a representation of your source data?  I'm not quite following your bullet points, so a visual may be best for A) what is currently happening and B) what is desired.

Comment: You could mock up some data to help, so you're not disclosing or breaching confidentiality.  Something to help the reader better understand your predicament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a formula in the *right table*'s **comment** column that shows the **comment** of the *left table*, if the given **name** and **amount** criteria is met.

The following solution can do it as long as:

- entries with the same name in the left table are in contiguous order
- the "any amount" can be expressed via a number.

[image]

In cell **G2**, I used the following formula, which can be copied down.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(F2,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$5,0),1,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,E2),1),1)+MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$5,0)-1)
```

Let me know, if you need an in-depth explanation.

**Note**: You can put in any number in column "B". The formula looks for a number that is smaller than the one in column "F". If I would change the amount in **B5** to 10, the cells **G7** and **G8** will show **N/A**. Thus you should define a comment for each *name* and the amount of *0* to avoid that or wrap the formula in an `IFNA` statement.